# Can I use server side code in Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have noticed when accessing windows mobile service I can schedule tasks to perform at certain times. I also noticed that the script to perform these tasks is only javascript? Is there a way I can use some server side code to perform a mobile service?

I want to be able to connect to an API. Check for a specific update. If that update is present send an email to myself.

Unfortunately this API suffers from the same-origin policy and doesn't offer a solution like JSONP. Therefore I will need to handle this API access server side.

Comment: WAMS uses server-side JS.

Comment: So I take it since it is server-side. Pulling the API data may work. I know it works when I pull it in C#. But it doesn't in pure client side JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested in Widows Azure Mobile Services because of the Scheduler service, as a simpler alternative to jobs running in Worker Roles with Quartz and other alternatives, but I felt the same difficulty you describe in having to work in a JS only environment, which is a problem in my scenario.

Are you aware of Windows Azure Web Site Web Jobs ([here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx))? You can configure continuous or scheduled jobs developed in many script languages as well as in .Net.

We moved many smaller tasks from under-utilized and more complex Worker Roles to Web Jobs as simple .Net console apps. Via the Web Jobs SDK you also get a [good monitoring environment](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/getting-started-with-windows-azure-webjobs#monitor).

Comment: Thanks I had not heard of web site web jobs before. I think this will work perfectly for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can only use JavaScript, but support for other languages (like C#) is [planned](http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services/suggestions/3315616-support-for-backend-languages-other-than-javascrip).